# Bias of MLEs increases rather than decreases in n

Tags: maximum-likelihood, bias, asymptotics

In the context of conducting simulations to assess the performance of MLE point estimates for truncated data, I am encountering surprising settings in which the bias of MLEs is clearly non-monotonic in the sample size, $n$. Not only is the bias non-monotonic, but in some scenarios, it shows a general pattern of increasing rather than decreasing in
$n$. See the dashed red line in this figure:

[image]

In this figure, the Y-axis is bias, and the X-axis is the sample size, with tick marks spaced on log scale. As MLE theory stipulates, the bias does of course eventually asymptote near 0, but only for $n >> 1000$ (not shown in figures). The empirical SE and RMSE (which is heavily dominated by the SE rather than the bias in this setting) both decline about monotonically in $n$.

I am saddened, yet intrigued, to see the bias of MLE behaving so badly for sample sizes up to $n=1000$.

#### My question

**Is there precedent in the statistics literature for any of the following?**

- Other empirical results establishing similarly non-monotonic bias of MLEs for any estimand?
- Theoretical results establishing general conditions under which MLEs exhibit non-monotonic finite-sample bias?
- Intuition for why this behavior occurs, apart from simply "MLE theory promises you nothing about finite-sample bias"?

Comment: I assume the nonmonotonicity isn't just a consequence of a small number of replications in the simulation exercise?

Comment: Correct! This is with 5,000 iterates, and the MCMC error bars were small enough to omit. I also see similar behavior across numerous scenarios, but chose just a few to show here.

Comment: What is the underlying distribution?  Without knowing that...

Comment: Standard normal with known truncation points, given in brackets in the plot.